# JQuery JSON ajax result storing for later use

Tags: jquery, ajax

Guys I need help on getting this working. Basically I'm trying to generate on demand select options from a PHP ajax call but I do not want to make the ajax all on each request to generate the select option.

I want to store the results in a variable and use it whenever I want to generate the select options.

This is a sample of the ajax call result.

```
{"status":"success",
 "tp":0,
 "msg":"Data fetched successfully.",
 "result":{
     "1":"response 1",
     "2":"response 2",
     "3":"response 3"}
}
```

This is my simplified code :

```
$(function () {

    var certList = getList('/ajaxx/ajax.getCertList.php');

    //rest of stuff here

}

function generateCertOptions(elem) {
    var data = certList;

    function generateOptions(data){

        console.log(data.tp); ]] //tried with certList and getting undefined here
        console.log(certList.tp); ]] //tried with data still getting undefined here

        if (data.tp == 0) {
            $.each(data['result'], function(index, value) {
                $(elem).append(new Option(value, index));
            })
        }
    }

    generateOptions(data);
};
```

Comment: You can cache your AJAX request

Comment: i dont see your other code, but your approach is right. you load your list at first, and then use it as variable, so what is the problem?

Comment: Why do you have a function nested inside another function?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is that `$(function () { });` creates it's own variable scope. This means that any variable defined inside it, can only be accessed by a function that is ALSO inside it.

So, inside `generateCertOptions()`, `certList` is in fact `undefined`.

Instead, you need to define the variable in the global scope, then SET the variable inside your on load function like this:

```js
var data; // global to store data needs to be OUTSIDE the "$(function () { });" 
$(function () {
    data = getList('/ajaxx/ajax.getCertList.php'); // don't use "var" here so it will use the global variable 
    $('#select1').html(generateCertOptions('#select1'));
    //rest of stuff here
    //...
    
    // later, use the cached value again
    $('#select2').html(generateCertOptions('#select2'));
  
});
function generateCertOptions(elem) {
    $.each(data['result'], function(index, value) {
         $(elem).append(new Option(value, index));
    })
};


// fake the ajax for this example
function getList(url){
  return {"status":"success",
           "tp":0,
           "msg":"Data fetched successfully.",
           "result":{
               "1":"response 1",
               "2":"response 2",
               "3":"response 3"}
          };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="select1"></select>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<select name="" id="select2"></select>
```

#### Additionally, you need to get rid of that nested function, which I have done above.

Comment: Thanks DelightedD0D for the quick answer and many thanks also for the lesson on Jquery. newbie in learning mode.

Comment: Happy to help, if you find that you need to store the data to be used on **multiple pages** of your site, you can store the data using  [local storage](http://www.webcodegeeks.com/html5/html5-local-storage-example/) just make sure you add logic to refresh the data when needed

Answer (score 0):

The function generateCertOptions() is read first, then your jQuery second.

Since you wrapped your certList variable with an anonymous function you no longer have access to it anywhere else, that's why you're getting undefined result. Also, as mentioned in the comment your structure is incorrect. You have a function wrapping a function for no reason.

```
var certList = null;
$(function() { certList = getList('/ajaxx/ajax.getCertList.php'); }
function generateOptions(data) { ... }
generateOptions(certList); // pass the data
```

This is a simple explanation of how you should approach it. I did not test this code.